# Sequelize query with ILIKE clause between multiple fields

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to do the following query equivalent in Sequelize

```sql
SELECT * FROM users u 
WHERE concat('%', u.name, '%', u.surname,'%') 
ILIKE '%?%?%';
```

Do you have some ideas of how to do a query like that in Sequelize, I already tried this, thinking it could be equivalent, but no luck.

```
user.findAll({
    where: {
      [Op.or]: [
        { name: { [Op.ilike]: '%someval%' } },
        { surname: { [Op.ilike]: '%someval%' } }
      ]
    }
  });
```

Comment: Simply use a "raw" SQL query with `sequelize.query(..)` ( http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html ) and ofcource protect it against SQl injections with prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks, @RaymondNijland, if I didn't find another way I will fall back to native query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `Op.iLike` (uppercase L)

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators